# Premature end of script headers (Perl)

Tags: perl, cgi

```
#!C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
$command=`perl -v`;
$title = "Perl Version";

print "Content-type: text/html\\n\\n";
print "<html><head><title>$title</title></head><body>";

print "
<h1>$title</h1>

\n";
print $command;

print "</body></html>";
```

I get this error:

> Premature end of script headers:
>   version.cgi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the extra backslash

This code:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\\n\\n";
```

Should be this:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

**EDIT**

Also, the first line in the script looks wrong.

```
#!C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
```

This should be the path to Perl, not httpd.

**EDIT 2**

Finally, this all would have been easier for you to solve if you added these two lines after the first line in your script:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
```

And run the script on the command line with the -c -w flags to compile-check and warnings-check your script, ie `perl -cw yourscript.cgi`.  This will give you line numbers of errors and warnings in your script.

Altogether, your script could look like this:

```
#!C:\path\to\perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;

my $command=$^V;
my $title = 'Perl Version';

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "
<html><head><title>$title</title></head><body>

<h1>$title</h1>

$command

</body></html>";
```

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, should be `Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n`

Comment: No, that's a CGI header, not an HTTP header. You don't need to use the HTTP line endings because the web server takes care of that for you.

Comment: Minor nit: You can have string literals across multiple lines without the continuation `\` at the end of each line.  They're not good for readability, and a heredoc should be used, but they do work.

Comment: Strings are allowed to span over multiple lines, and \ is only needed in Shell programming, not Perl. `q`/`qq` are not functions, but [operators](http://p3rl.org/op#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: @Mark and @daxim - Wow, I was completely wrong about " and ' string literals spanning multiple lines...thank you!

Comment: Ah, so just the path to perl was incorrect. Worked! Thanks x10!! :)

Comment: @daxim, Named operators (like `qq` and `print`) are often called functions.

Answer (score 2):

You have written `\\n` where it should be `\n` in the header.

ETA: Also, `perl -v` is not a very good way to get the version. The variable `$^V` contains a more succinct and specific version number.